# How to display logoUrl in third party conference dropdown using apps scipt

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, gsuite-addons

While developing google calendar add-on, 'My Meetings'  is getting displayed in 'Add Conference' dropdown, but icon is not getting displayed.

```
 "calendar": {
      "conferenceSolution": [{
        "onCreateFunction": "createConference",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "My Meetings",
        "logoUrl": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/sgkt743sv30rid1/logo-circuit-100x100.png?dl=0"
      }],
```

What can be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### The manifest structure has been [changed recently](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/01/gsuite-add-ons-generally-available.html)

Now, the correct [field specification](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/upgrade-addons#step_3_update_your_add-ons_manifest) has been modified from

`calendar.logoUrl`

to

`addOns.common.logoUrl`.

Comment: I have followed same recent structure..Can you please help me with where should I upload logo for the logoUrl for displaying in add conference dropdown?

Comment: I have seen you filed a bug about this issue - you might be right. The  third party conference solution has been pushed through recently and there might still be propagation issues.

Comment: Actually I wanted to know Where should I upload the image in order to see in add conference dropdown..zoom meeting has this kind of logo url, which is working properly. [https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ugWKRyPiOCwjn5jfaoVgC-O80F3nhKH1dKMGsibXvGV1tc6pGXLOJk9WO7dwhw8-Xl9IwkKZEFDbeMDgnx-kf8YGJZ9uhrJM] How can I get this kind of URL?

Comment: In principle you can upload it anywhere, but I tested it and it seems that right now it's not working no matter where you upload the image - so seems to be an issue from Google's side indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. I tried to solve it by storing it google cloud storage and then I open the image (png 120x120) in my browser and right click it and 'Copy Image Address'. It worked that way, problem is, that url will expire.

I'll try [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/serving-static-files?tab=python) approach using gsutil command line tool. That should do the trick.